# SEO - Custom error pages & status codes

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, googlebot, 404, error

My website uses a custom error page with the `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">` meta tag.

Am I right in thinking this tag will tell crawlers, such as Googlebot, to remove the page from their index?

Should I also be setting the HTTP status code accordingly, e.g. HTTP 404, or will this affect SEO performance?

Answer (score 1):

> Should I also be setting the HTTP status code accordingly, e.g. HTTP 404

Absolutely yes! With this alone you send a signal to Google to not index it. Your meta robots will be in this case a kind of redundant rule.

But, if Google mistakenly already indexed your error page - just let your robots be, adjust 404 status code correctly - and after some time Google will remove it from index.

Comment: If the correct 404 status is used, there is no need for the meta tag to prevent indexing.